# PHP search function not returning image

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Playing around with php and still new to it etc. I got my search function to work , and it gets all the data back fine. Only problem is that it won't display the image for each recipe I have.

```
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0) {
        $output = 'There was mo match!';
    }else{
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $pic = $row['pix'];

            $output .= '
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading"><b>' . htmlentities($rN, ENT_QUOTES) . '</b></div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="pull-left col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" src="'. htmlentities($pic, ENT_QUOTES) . '">
```

I have tried a lot of diffrent versions etc but like i said i am so new to this that i am still trying to get my head around it. All the other functions work fine etc. The main bit of code which wont work is :

```
<img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" src="'. htmlentities($pic, ENT_QUOTES) . '">
```

If anyone can help me fix this . It would be great.
Thanks for the help

P.S I know about the sql injections :) but 1 step at a time for now x

Comment: Can you give an example value for `$pic` or `$row['pix']`?

Comment: `var_dump();` or `var_dump($row['pix']);` reveals what and what is the value for it? also look at your HTML source. Plus, unsure if you should be using `htmlentities()` here.

Comment: Sidenote: You can safely remove one of the `$count = mysql_num_rows($query);`, you have 2x.

Comment: pix is what i stroed the images on in the sql database

Comment: as a blob and just used the way i called the other things in here such as title and the ingredents to do the same thing for image

Comment: So OR pix LIKE '%$searchq%'

Comment: try removing it `src="'. $pic . '">` or `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $pic ).'"/>` type of thing. That one's a jpg method if it's jpg

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry i dont understand what u mean :) Could you please explain the direct line of code i should try

Comment: replace `src="'. htmlentities($pic, ENT_QUOTES) . '"` with `src="'. $pic . '"` or try `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $pic ).'"/>`

Comment: @Fred-ii- u sir are a beautiful man! Thanks , it was the second line one that worked. The first one just gave me ramdom symbols, second one worked a charm, will update it now xx

Comment: I'll post an answer then ;-) @Nevershow2016

Comment: @Fred-ii- be my guest x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment and the OP's wish:

Replace `src="'. htmlentities($pic, ENT_QUOTES) . '"` with

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $pic ).'"/>
```

Since the column type is a BLOB.

[`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) is a totally different animal and is mostly used for strings.

> string htmlentities ( string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 [, string $encoding = ini_get("default_charset") [, bool $double_encode = true ]]] )

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 and has been removed from PHP 7.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Comment: @Nevershow2016 Always a pleasure, *cheers* :-) and you're welcome.